# Bin data from an imported excel file by adding 5 elemets of y axis each

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, matrix

So i imported a file from excel and viewed it as a grid. but now i need to add groups of 5 elements from the y axis and plot them against every fifth entry from the x axis. Thanks

Edit: Sorry about less datails. (its my first day using mathematica, i have very superficial knowledge only)

So I imported an excel file as

```
k = Import["\\\\myfiles.campus\\~\\y.xlsx", {"Data", 1, All, {7, 2}}]
```

then selected the data i needed as

```
r = k[[67 ;; 1499, All]]
```

until now i can plot this using listplot.

now that i have the graph, my data looks like:

```
{{6.91647*10^-7, 61.}, {7.02127*10^-7, 56.}, {7.12606*10^-7, 50.}, 
 {7.23085*10^-7, 48.}, {7.33565*10^-7, 44.}, {7.44045*10^-7, 37.}, 
 {7.54524*10^-7, 34.}}
```

way more than this.

so now i plot this as

```
g = ListPlot[k, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{.000000691647, .0000156983}, {0, 61}}]
```

but now i try to fit the function

```
Fit = NonlinearModelFit[g , aExp[bt] + c, {a, b, c}, t]
```

which doesnt go through as i have 0's as my y axis.

So i thought i should bin the data and add them into groups of 5 which should resolve the problem, but cannot do that. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I'm pretty certain you should not be passing in a `ListPlot` as your data into `NonlinearModelFit`. Your code above passes `g` to `NonlinearModelFil` and `g` is a `ListPlot` not a list of data. Could that be your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you've given enough information but here's my take:

```
in = Sort@RandomReal[1, {20, 2}];  (* input *)

original = ListPlot[in, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
grouped = ListPlot@Flatten[
   Thread /@ 
    Transpose@{in[[5 ;; ;; 5, 1]], Partition[in[[All, 2]], 5]},
   1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare:

```
Show[original, grouped]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I just edited the question to make it clearer, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The data you have given is clearly insufficient to provide a concrete answer, but here is my attempt:

```
data = {{6.91647*10^-7, 61.}, {7.02127*10^-7, 56.}, {7.12606*10^-7, 
   50.}, {7.23085*10^-7, 48.}, {7.33565*10^-7, 44.}, {7.44045*10^-7, 
   37.}, {7.54524*10^-7, 34.}}

g = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]

fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, a Exp[b t] + c, {a, b, c}, t]

fun = Normal[fit]

Show[g, Plot[fun, {t, 6*10^-7, 8*10^-7}]]
```

This fit seems reasonable since I only have 7 data points. Not sure what you mean by  "as i have 0's as my y axis." Also you are feeding the plot (g) into the fitting function. Feed the data instead!